# boost 100ns pulse from 5 v to 10 v

Tags: voltage, frequency, boost, pulse

I have to amplify or "step up" the voltage of a pulse generator.

I have a pulse generator, which generates 5 volt pulses with on times ranging from 100nano seconds to 1200 nano seconds which repeats itself approximately every 1milisecond .

For design reasons I need to get the same pulse but at 10 or 20 volt in amplitude, without compromising the the pulse times .

My initial thoughts were using an schmitt-trigger as a buffer but It couldn't handle the high frequency of oscillation .

How can I create a pulse from 5V to 10V that lasts 100ns? Can I do this with a capacitor and a mosfet?

Comment: You need to decide what load you need to drive (resistance and capacitance), what the output slew rate requirements are and   what delay can you tolerate.  Can the output amplitude be fixed or need to depend upon the input amplitude?

Comment: Your task is not defined? please specify: (1) the load: resistance and capacitance; (2) required rise and fall times; (3) is inversion acceptable (gain -2..-4) or not (gain 2..4).

Comment: I need to drive an NMOS transistor

Comment: You must never start any design until you know all the pertinent specs., slew rate, overshoot, voltage, load impedance ( R-L-C) frequency

Comment: This means define your pulse source impedance or type  (e.g. 74HCxx  and load for 20V pulse where slew rate implies current with load capacitance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider just using a fast comparator such as a [LM1711/1712](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/171112f.pdf)

They will operate with a 10V or even 12V supply. At currents of 1mA or less you'll get almost the whole supply swing at the output.

Output rise and fall times are in the 2ns range with a 10pF load, and propagation delay is less than 5ns typically with 20mV overdrive.

---

A more Neanderthal method would be to drive the gate of a smallish MOSFET such as an 2N7002 **hard** with something like a fast CMOS inverting buffer and use a very low value of pullup resistor to 10V or 12V (something like 100 ohms, which would consume 100-120mA with your very low duty cycle.

Minimize loop inductance by keeping everything very compact and use very good supply bypassing right near the transistor/resistor.

Comment: Spehro how should I use the comparator for voltage boosting?

Comment: The output voltage swings between the supplies, so give it enough supply voltage. Probably you can overdrive the *** out of the inputs, so try connecting the + input to your 5V logic signal and the - input to 2.5V (say from a voltage divider 1k+1K to +5 and ground).

Comment: This is an espectacular answer, unfortunately I can't get ahold of those in my country, luckily a member of my team came up with a brilliant solution consisting in a nmos followed by a mos push- pull stage, driving the *** out of the fets. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Look for high gain bandwidth product op-amps such as in excess of 500 MHz. If you want to maintain fast rise and fall times look for devices with 1000 volt/microsecond slew rates or more. All the main players do something in this sort of area. Try ADI, TI and LT and maybe even Maxim. All those players have excellent search machines.